# Как реализовать фильтрацию через набор текста в элементе DevExpress ComboBoxEdit в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, devexpress

Имеется на WPF-форме Элемент dxe:ComboBoxEdit. Необходимо сделать фильтрацию, чтобы при наборе текста отфильтровывал отображение существующих элементов ComboBox. Источник элементов привязан через биндинги из View-модели к коллекции элементов типа ObservableCOllection. Вот пример кода на XAML:

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
 Margin="10,30,5,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="NaN" 
 RenderTransformOrigin="0.451,0.773"
 ItemsSource="{Binding QualityObjects}"
 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedQualityObject}"
 DisplayMember="Name" 
 IsReadOnly="False">`
```

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов - у ComboBoxEdit создается событие EditValueChanged и там пишется что - то такое:

```
var newListName =  
  QualityObjects.Where(n=>n.Name.Contains((string)e.NewValue)).ToList();
```

Я думаю что ход мыслей понятен.